# Making cUrl http request on a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl, httprequest

I was wondering if there is a way to know if the http request made to a rails app is in cUrl?

I have a code that does some front-end process and is specific only for http request done through the web browser. Now, I want to be able to differentiate the normal http request to a cUrl request so that I can make another process only for cUrl request.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if request.env["HTTP_USER_AGENT"] =~ /curl/i
```

in your controller should do the trick. Or you can do this in the routing level with the user agent option:

```
get '/resource' => 'Controller#curl_logic', constraints: {user_agent: /curl/i}
get '/resource/' => 'Controller#view_logic' # everything else
```

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the user-agent in the HTTP request but that will only work if the curl client doesn't override it, which is easy to do. If you're only doing this for 'friendly' clients where you can trust the user-agent, it's straightforward. See the first example in [one of the better resources for rails routing](http://railsdispatch.com/posts/rails-3-makes-life-better).